# ffmpeg : CPU, ram or SSD?

Tags: video, ssd, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3

I want to know what is the most important to convert a mp4 file to mp3 thanks to ffmpeg. CPU ? RAM ? SSD ? The threes ?

My server will convert 3-5 mp4 videos to mp3 at the same time. Duration of the videos : 10 minutes.

I need to make it the fastest possible, so I want to take a VPS or dedicated server from OVH.com (debian 9). Could you tell me which server to take ? I want to put $25 max.

https://www.ovh.com/fr/vps/vps-ssd.xml

https://www.ovh.com/fr/vps/vps-cloud.xml

https://www.kimsufi.com/fr/serveurs.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the video already have mp3 audio, disk io will be your bottleneck. If you need to convert just a few file (say under 100) CPU raw speed (ghz) is desired. If you need to convert many thousands, CPU cores to run more parallel encodes is better.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to convert video files to audio, both CPU and disk will be your primary priorities.

You'll be writing a lot less than you're reading, so good read performance is a must. Depending on how many CPU cores and thus how many parallel encodes you want to go for, you'll need appropriately more disk I/O to accomplish that. Basically, this is one case where neither CPU nor disk *alone* represents the "biggest" bottleneck; adding more CPU cores requires proportionally more disk I/O.

Modern CPUs can encode MP3 audio at around 30-40x realtime on one core. If you have plenty of I/O and lots of cores, you could have even a large number of videos converted in mere minutes. Most VPS environments today run on SSD so you will likely have plenty of disk usage to begin with, so spring for more than one CPU core for the job. (Also note however that you need to get the content up to the VPS, and if you're doing that via the Internet, that will likely be the *slowest* part of your process.)